# What does the star mean in this haskell code?

Tags: haskell

I found this code in the unm-hip package.
So Pixel is a function ?

```
class Imageable i where
  type Pixel i :: *
  rows :: i -> Int
  cols :: i -> Int
  ref  :: i -> Int -> Int -> (Pixel i)
  makeImage :: Int -> Int -> PixelOp (Pixel i) -> i
  pixelList :: i -> [Pixel i]
  pixelList i = [ ref i r c | r <- [0..(rows i - 1)], c <- [0..(cols i - 1)]]
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As an extension to standard Haskell, you can deal with "kinds". Kinds are sort of a very basic type system for types and type constructors. Kind `*` is a simple type, like `Int`. Kind `* -> *` is a type constructor that takes a type and yields a type, like `Maybe`: pass it a type like `Int` as an argument, and you get the type `Maybe Int`.

The other extension used in this code (which I didn't notice at first, since the indentation was lost) is associated types. A typeclass in standard Haskell can specify a number of functions that the type must support. With associated types, it can additionally specify types and type constructors that are associated with the type.

Here, this means that a type `i` that is an instance of `Imageable` (i.e. behaves like an image) must have an associated pixel type `Pixel i`, and this must be a simple type (kind `*`), not a type constructor.

Comment: There isn't much choice. You have some kind of type that represents an image, and the typeclass needs functions that deal with a single pixel in the image. You need some way to find out what the type of that pixel is. You could fix it, but that's not very flexible. You could make Imageable a multi-param typeclass over the image and its pixel, but then you need functional dependencies or type ambiguities will drive you crazy, and you still need to mention the pixel type in every signature that uses the class. Associated types are much cleaner and easier.

Answer (score 2):

"So Pixel is a function?"

Pixel is a type-level function.  It takes a single type (which must be an instance of Imageable) and returns a type of kind '*'.  Based on it's usage in the example code, the input type must also be of kind '*'.  So, Pixel is very much like Maybe, they are both  "type constructors" of kind '* -> *', you provide them a "simple type" and they return a "simple type".  They are also valid in the same locations.  Just like you can't have a function of type 'Foo -> Maybe', you also won't be able to have a function of type 'Bar -> Pixel'.

Comment: So the `type` keyword is not as with a haskell Type Synonyms keyword right ? If it's as you said why isn't it written like this: `type Pixel :: i->*`

Comment: @osager It's related, but not the same.  When you provide an (Imagable my_image) instance, your definition for Pixel must be an existing type and (Pixel my_image) will be an alias / synonym for that type.  It's a GHC extension called (open) type families.