# Restrictions on Types of `a -> b` Function

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have part of a function's signature:

`f :: (a -> b) -> ...`

Is there any restriction (such as their `kinds`) on the types of `a` and `b`?

`a` can't be a function, i.e. `(c -> d)`, can it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a` and `b` must have kind `*`, that is they must not be type constructors that require arguments. So they could be `Integer`, `(c -> d)` or `Maybe String`, but not `(->)`, `(a ->)` or `Maybe`.

> `a` can't be a function, i.e. `(c -> d)`, can it?

Yes, it can. It can be any possible type of kind `*`.

Comment: Ah, so when the word `type` is used, it's implied to have a `kind` of `*`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith That may not have been technically correct on my part. I changed my wording to be more clear.

Comment: For an explanation of the kind `*`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22807963/1186208), or [this section of the GHC 7.4.2 docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.2/docs/html/users_guide/kind-polymorphism-and-promotion.html). (The current docs seem to have dropped that initial discussion.) I casually think of `*` as the kind of types with *values* (including function values, of course), but that may not be quite correct.

Comment: "I casually think of * as the kind of types with values (including function values, of course), but that may not be quite correct.".  Perhaps it's slightly more correct to say that * is the kind of "types containing *run-time* values", since there are other kinds which contain type-level values (e.g. under GHC -XDataTypes, type-level literals 0, 1, 2 have kind Nat). Apart from this nuance, I think your intuition is valid.

Comment: I couldn't find an existing question squarely on this topic, so I made one: [what exactly is `*`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095011/)